# Required Column not showing as required from UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, infragistics

I have datacolumns that are marked as required in database objects that do not allow null values.  This works fine when the user manually inserts a record from the UI.  All required columns show up with a red exclamation next to them and users are unable to save until all required columns have been populated.

Issue I ran into is when attempting to insert records dynamically using a toolclick action.  The code works as expected and adds records to the child pane and even prevents a user from saving if one of the required columns are not populated.  However, the columns are not showing up as required like they would when manually inserting row from UI.  Is there a way to get the red exclamation to show up like it would when manually inserting the record?

```
public UiEventResult ToolClick_Default_Valuation_Rows_After_1()
{
//active row in UI view that toolclick will be associated with
UltraGridRow ultraGridRow = _view.ViewGrids["view"].ActiveRow;

DataRow newDataRow;

newDataRow = _view.DataSource.Tables["table"].NewRow();
newDataRow["column"] = DBNull.Value;
_view.DataSource.Tables["table"].Rows.Add(newDataRow);       

return new UiEventResult(EventStatus.Continue);
}
```

Comment: My apologies that should probably have come out.  Updating syntax.  I'm thinking the question should just address how to enforce database object properties when inserting rows from a class event using NewRow from a ToolClick.  The database will still restrict adding and enforce the requirement on the column but its just not highlighted as required like it would be if the user inserted from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
public UiEventResult InitView_1()
    {
        UltraGrid ultraGrid1 = _view.ViewGrids["view"];
        ultraGrid1.DataSource = _view.DataSource.Tables["table"];
        ultraGrid1.UpdateMode |= UpdateMode.OnUpdate;
        
        return new UiEventResult(EventStatus.Continue);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).